# Bitbucket pipelines & AWS Codeartifact integration via OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codeartifact

I'm following this [article](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-on-aws-using-bitbucket-pipelines-openid-connect/) to make Bitbucket pipelines work with AWS Codeartifact but having troubles with it.

I've

1. Created "Identity Provider" with URL & Audience from Bitbucket's OIDC settings.
2. Created a AWS role with `AWSCodeArtifactAdminAccess` permissions and associated it with the Identity Provider
3. Defined 2 Bitbucket's repository variables:
   `AWS_REGION` & `AWS_ROLE_ARN`.
4. Created `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file that looks like this:

```
image:
  name: XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bitbucket-docker:1.0.0
  aws:
    oidc-role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/bitbucket-pipelines
options:
  max-time: 30 # per-step timeout in minutes

pipelines:
  branches:
    default:
      - step:
          oidc: true
          script:
            - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
            - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token
            - aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/bitbucket-pipelines --role-session-name build-session  --web-identity-token "$BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN" --duration-seconds 1000

    develop:
      - step:
          name: Verify after merge to 'develop' Branch
          oidc: true
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
            - mvn verify -DskipTests

  custom:
    release:
      - step:
          name: Release
          oidc: true
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
            - mvn verify deploy -e -DskipTests
```

When I run the `custom release` goal which deploys to Codeartifact I can see that I'm able to access the ECR docker image, but getting 401 authentication error when trying to deploy the maven artifacts (jar file).

I'm under the impression that I don't need to call `aws codeartifact get-authorization-token` since I authenticate via OIDC.

Any idea what am I missing here?

**EDIT1:**
Please notice, on the example I followed they call the following command:

```
aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/bitbucket-pipelines --role-session-name build-session  --web-identity-token "$BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN" --duration-seconds 1000
```

with `--role-session-name build-session`

I wonder about `build-session` is that a default name or probably I should put something else, what??

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned on [Atlassian group](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-pipelines-integrations-with-AWS-CodeArtifact-via-OIDC/qaq-p/2439708), you need to obtain token for CodeArtifact itself.

So first, obtain Federated identity for AWS, and in subsequent command get `CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN`. For example like this:

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain xxxx --domain-owner 123456 --region eu-central-1 --query authorizationToken --output text`
```

Whole working example by me:

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-21

steps:
  - step: &get-token
      name: Get Authorization token
      image: amazon/aws-cli
      oidc: true
      script:
        - export AWS_REGION=eu-central-1
        - export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/oidc-demo
        - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
        - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token
        - aws sts get-caller-identity
        - export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain xxxx --domain-owner 123456 --region eu-central-1 --query authorizationToken --output text`
        - set > .env
      artifacts:
        - .env

  - step: &build
      name: Build
      caches:
        - maven
      script:
        - set -a && . .env && set +a
        - mvn -s ci_settings.xml clean package -DskipTests -P bitbucket -U

  - step: &unit-test
      name: JUnit test
      caches:
        - maven
      script:
        - set -a && . .env && set +a
        - mvn -s ci_settings.xml test -P bitbucket -U

  - step: &deploy-artifact
      name: Deploy artifact
      caches:
        - maven
      script:
        - set -a && . .env && set +a
        - mvn -s ci_settings.xml deploy -DskipTests -P bitbucket -U

pipelines:

  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *get-token
      - step: *build
      - step: *unit-test


  branches:

    master:
      - step: *get-token
      - step: *build
      - step: *unit-test
      - step: *deploy-artifact
```

**ci_settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <servers>

    <server>
      <id>xxxxx</id>
      <username>aws</username>
      <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>

  </servers>
</settings>
```